# SMTP outgoing server does not send text inside the email by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, email, smtp

I developed apart of an application that sends emails to partners and clients with a saved email subject and text; so i used the vb.net settings to declare variables to be initiated with the program. and then asked the user to save his email subject and body to be used again later.
the problem is when i attemped to send the email, the email reaches the otherside yet with no content at all ( mail subject and body are null).
some points may be taken into consideration:

- i used background worker (thread dirrent than the UI thread)
- the outgoing mail is SMTP (Gmail server).
- I passes the Body and the subject as strings to the sub sendmail().

  - Is there any better method to store mail's body and subject instead of string variables ?
- I am sure that the SMTP took all my strings

  ```
  Sub sendmail(receiver As String, mailsubject As String, mailbody As String, mailattachement As String)
  Dim email As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
  Dim smtp As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
  Try
              With smtp
                  .EnableSsl = My.Settings.mailssl
                  .Port = My.Settings.mailport
                  .Host = My.Settings.mailhost
                  .Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(My.Settings.mailaddress, My.Settings.mailpassword)
              End With

              With email
                  .From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(My.Settings.mailaddress)
                  .Subject = severalclientmailsubject
                  .Body = severalclientmailbody
                  .To.Add(receiver)
              End With
                  smtp.Send(email)                   
      Catch ex As Exception
      'Generic Exception raised.
      changestatus2("General Error.")
      End Try
  End Sub
  ```

what could can cause this thing ?!?

Comment: Where do you set `severalclientmailsubject` and `severalclientmailbody`?  The values passed to your function are named mailsubject and mailbody.

Comment: in a separate module yet they are defined as public @JimmySmith

Comment: So if you set a breakpoint at `.Subject = severalclientmailsubject` and do a watch on severalclientmailsubject - you can see it has the expected value?  My theory is it's just not getting set somewhere if the email is going through.

Comment: actually, i moved the variable to the class where  the code relays on, and it worked. very weird !! i guess i should have named the module name first as for example: (module1.severalclientmailbody)

Comment: Nice!  Without an explicit reference to the module it will not access it.  .Net is pretty picky about this.  In Visual Basic 6 or VBA, then you're ok with referencing a public variable without typing out the module the public variable is in.  This modern behavior does help keep things separated if you're in a big project.

Comment: thank you very much!! you are such a wonderful genius !! appreciate you great help !!